# Python multiprocessing: Kill producer and consumer processes with KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, keyboardinterrupt

I want the customer and producer processes to stop in the following python script if the keyboard shortcut `CTRL+C` is performed. But the processes do not stop - the keyboard interrupt is not passed to them. Also the except block of the main process is never entered.

```py
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
import signal

class Consumer(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        proc_name = self.name
        try:
            while True:
                print("{}".format(proc_name))
                time.sleep(3)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("{} stopped".format(proc_name)) # never printed
        return

class Producer(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(3)
                print("Producer here.")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Producer stopped.") # never printed
        return

def main():
    def __init_worker():
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
        print('init') # not printed!!??

#    manager = SyncManager() # does not change anything
#    manager.start(__init_worker)

    consumers = [Consumer(target=__init_worker) for i in xrange(3)]
    producer = Producer(target=__init_worker)

    producer.daemon = True # does not change anything
    producer.start()
    for c in consumers:
        c.daemon = True
        c.start()

    try:
        producer.join()
        for c in consumers:
            c.join()
    except Exception as e:
        print('STOP') # never printed
        raise e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There might be also a solution for my task by using `multiprocesing.Pool` for the customers and let the main process work as producer, but I would like to know why my implementation is not working as it is intended to and  what I need to adjust.

I realised that `__init_worker` seems to be not executed (makes no difference if it is located outside of `main`). Maybe the reason for not passing `KeyboardInterrupt` to the customer and producer processes?

Comment: You're overriding `run`, the method that calls the process `_target` attribute. So `__init_worker` is definitely not executed.

Comment: To easy explanation. Is it somehow possible to pass the content of my function `run` to the super `run`? Just calling 'super.run()` does not work I assume.

Comment: It's `super(Producer, self).run()`, and so on. In Python 3 you can use  `super()` without arguments. The default `Process.run` calls the object's `_target`, if any, and returns. But typically a `threading.Thread` or `multiprocessing.Process` subclass that implements `run` wouldn't use the `target` parameter.

Comment: Yes, that calls `__init_worker` but still `CTRL+C` does not stop the processes.

Comment: You're ignoring `SIGINT` in the child processes, so what do you expect to raise `KeyboardInterrupt`? Normally that's raised by Python's default `SIGINT` handler, `signal.default_int_handler`.

Comment: I was searching around and the `SIGINT` stuff was used as a solution in a lot of sample implementations and also works fine in combination with `multiprocessing.Pool` - I do not really know yet what it does

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 but it would be nice if the script is also running on other systems

Comment: If you want an ordered shutdown of the child processes, rather than all of them individually handling `KeyboardInterrupt`, disabling Ctrl+C in the child processes is fine. You just need a shared synchronization object such as `quit_event = mp.Event()`. The main process would handle `KeyboardInterrupt` by setting this event.

Comment: Supporting Windows is more work since the `join()` calls can't be interrupted by Ctrl+C on Windows. There are workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on eryksun's comments I improved my code and use `multiprocessing.Event` now. And the script is now working like expected. I also removed some lines, which I think are not necessary any more. Since I did not find any similar solution when searching the web, here my code comes:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

class Consumer(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, quit_event, **kwargs):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.quit_event = quit_event

    def run(self):
        proc_name = self.name
        while not self.quit_event.is_set():
            print("{}".format(proc_name))
            time.sleep(3)
        print("{} stopped".format(proc_name))
        return

class Producer(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, quit_event, **kwargs):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.quit_event = quit_event

    def run(self):
        while not self.quit_event.is_set():
            print("Producer here.")
            time.sleep(3)
        print("Producer stopped")
        return


def main():
    quit_event = mp.Event()

    consumers = [Consumer(quit_event) for i in xrange(3)]
    producer = Producer(quit_event)

    producer.start()
    for c in consumers:
        c.start()

    try:
        producer.join()
        for c in consumers:
            c.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print('\nSTOP')
        quit_event.set()
    except Exception as e:
        quit_event.set()
        raise e
    finally:
        producer.terminate()
        producer.join()
        for c in consumers:
            c.terminate()
            c.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hoping, that it helps somebody.

Edit: Swaped `terminate` and `join` statements.